# Mongodb custom object id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase

If I want to use custom object id(using firebase user uid) in a mongodb model, then do I have to do anything thing different in model declaration or at the time of saving instance of the model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is perfectly fine to use firebase user uid for an object id, if some value is present in _id field of a document being stored, it is treated as objectId.

Just make sure every object has a unique _id as _id is indexed and is used as primary key.

Comment: At the time of defining the model will it be like this?          _id: { type: String}

Comment: yes and use unique: true as well to keep it unique since _id is a primary key