# Using shortid as custom Object ID in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, identifier

Following up with [Mongodb custom object id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52477859/mongodb-custom-object-id) & [Creating custom Object ID in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211138/creating-custom-object-id-in-mongodb), I want to use shortid as custom Object ID in MongoDB. Here is my relevant Go code:

```golang
type Book struct {
    _id       string
    Title     string
    Author    string
    ISBN      string
    Publisher string
    Copies    int
}

. . .

    id := shortid.MustGenerate()
    book1 := Book{id, "Animal Farm", "George Orwell", "0451526341", "Signet Classics", 100}
    insertResult, err := booksCollection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), book1)
```

It should be the case that,

> if some value is present in _id field of a document being stored, it is treated as objectId.

However, I found that my shortid is still being replaced by MongoDB:

> [image]

So, is it still possible?
Is there anything that I've done wrong? thx

Comment: You must use exported fields. `_id` is not exported. Use e.g. `ID string \`bson:"_id"\``

Comment: BINGO! Thx @icza !